# Multiple tinyMCE getContent() fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have multiple tinyMCE4 textareas on mye page, which I (all at once) initialize like this:

```
<script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector: 'textarea',
        /* ... more options ..*/
    });
</script>
<script src="js/myScript.js"></script>
```

In `myScript.js` I'd like to get the content of each one of the textareas, which look like this:

```
<textarea id="editor_1" data-field="1" class="editor"></textarea>
<textarea id="editor_2" data-field="2" class="editor"></textarea>
etc...
```

I tried this with this (on button click):

```
$(document).on('click','.saveStandardDoc',function(){
    $('.editor').each(function(i, obj) {
        var $that = $(this);
        console.log(tinyMCE.get($that).getContent());
    });
});
```

Now it gives me `tinyMCE.get is not a function` (does not matter if `tinymce` or `tinyMCE`)

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Maybe this helps ► [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16016250/how-to-get-tinymce-content-from-more-than-one-text-area](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16016250/how-to-get-tinymce-content-from-more-than-one-text-area)

Comment: It actually does, thank you! Couldnt find that information in the docs!

Answer (score 0):

The `get()` method expects the passed parameter to be a `String` that contains the `id` of the `<textarea>` that was replaced with TinyMCE.

In your code you are passing a jQuery reference to the `get()` method and that won't work.

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/root_tinymce/#get

A valid example would be:

```
tinymce.get('myEditor')
```

(note you don't pass a `#` at the beginning - its not looking for a CSS selector)